# How to say "traffic jam" in Ukrainian?

Tags: переклад, from-english, різниця-між-словами

I've heard several ways how people say about traffic jam: "пробка", "затор", "корок".

From [Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) I see that all these words are acceptable.

Is that correct? Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 12):

"Словник української мови 1970-1980" dictionary (aka СУМ-11) has two of the words you asked in this meaning:

- **Затор** is a proper way to say 'traffic jam' according to this dictionary. This jam can be caused by cars, by people, etc.:

  > [Затор](http://sum.in.ua/s/zator)
  >
  > 1. Скупчення людей, транспорту і т. ін., що створює перешкоду рухові. Піонери посунули до дверей і утворили затор (Олександр Копиленко, Тв., 1955, 197); Авто бігло далі на схід.. Несподівано спинилось в однім місці через затор великої кількості двоколок, підвід та автомобілів (Євген Кротевич, Вибр., 1959, 333);
- **Пробка** is colloquial for 'jamming' the way or path.

  > [Пробка](http://sum.in.ua/s/probka)
  >
  > 3. Те, що загороджує доступ, прохід куди-небудь, заважаючи дії, функціонуванню чогось.
  >      //  перен., розм. Скупчення кого-, чого-небудь, що запруджує прохід, проїзд і т. ін., заважаючи рухові.
- **Корок** has no 'traffic jam' meaning according to this dictionary. I think this is just a translation of 'пробка' (bottle cork) from Russian to Ukrainian. Update: корок has 'traffic jam' meaning in the modern "Словник української мови 2010–…" (aka СУМ-20):

  > [Корок](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44247&page=1400)
  >
  > 4. перен., розм. Те саме, що зато́р 1. Вулиці перекриті, машини сигналять, люди запізнюються на роботу, скрізь корки, вже сталося кілька аварій (Л. Костенко); На вулицях панував величезний рух, міліцейські будки опустіли, авта стояли в корку (Ю. Винничук); Корок на дорогах потроху розсмоктувався
  >      (І. Роздобудько).

However this dictionary is considered to have strong Russian-language influence. So, to seek true Ukrainian words you may want to look into dictionaries collected on r2u.org.ua site.

There you'll find the following words.

- Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов):

  > Затор подвод - **заві́з** (not about cars, but about carriages though)
- Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)

  > Зато́ръ = 2. **тїсно́та, тиск, ти́снява.** *— Така тїснота, що й києм не протиснеш. С. Ш. — І хлопцїв чортів тиск було. С. Ш. — Така тиснява, що й не пропхаєшся.* (examples show that this is about people)

I don't know what is the credibility of the last one dictionary, but nevertheless:

- Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–

  > I. Затор – (дорожный) **ти́снява, зато́ра, затор, за́пин (запи́на), запі́р (запо́ра), тромб**:
  >
  > - затор подвод – **заві́з** (about carriages);
  > - на перекрёстке затор – на перехресті **затора (тиск, тиснява, тромб)** (about jam on crossroads);
  > - сильные заторы на дорогах – дороги (шляхи) **заторовано**. *[В мене під вікнами третю добу **затор** (Ю.Джугастрянська). Ширлі <...>, вилаявши двох-трьох водіїв, зуміла вирватися із **запруги** (Я.Кравець, перекл. К.Панколь). Вдаримо по дорожніх **заторах** рекордними цінами на бензин!]* (about heavy traffic on the roads)