# Вживання слів затор чи корок?

Tags: значення-слів, синоніми

Велика кількість ЗМІ вживають *корок*, проте деякі мовознавці заперечують.

Чи могли б ви допомогти визначити значення обох слів?

Та яке з них є доречним у випадку коли це стосується автомобільної "Пробки"

Comment: Те саме питання, тільки англійською: [How to say “traffic jam” in Ukrainian?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/850/)

Answer (score 5):

Перекладаю [відповідь](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/867/240) Artemix з питання англійською мовою.

"Словник української мови 1970-1980" (СУМ-11) має два слова з таким значенням:

- **Затор** - це правильний спосіб казати про скупчення людей або транспорту:

  > [Затор](http://sum.in.ua/s/zator)
  >
  > 1. Скупчення людей, транспорту і т. ін., що створює перешкоду рухові. Піонери посунули до дверей і утворили затор (Олександр Копиленко, Тв., 1955, 197); Авто бігло далі на схід.. Несподівано спинилось в однім місці через затор великої кількості двоколок, підвід та автомобілів (Євген Кротевич, Вибр., 1959, 333);
- **Пробка** це розмовне слово на позначення чогось, що заважає проїзду або проходу.

  > [Пробка](http://sum.in.ua/s/probka)
  >
  > 3. Те, що загороджує доступ, прохід куди-небудь, заважаючи дії, функціонуванню чогось.
  >      //  перен., розм. Скупчення кого-, чого-небудь, що запруджує прохід, проїзд і т. ін., заважаючи рухові.
- **Корок** не має значення "затору" у цьому словнику. Скоріш за все, це просто переклад слова 'пробка' з російською на українську. Оновлення: корок має значення "затору" в сучасному «Словнику української мови» в 20 томах (2010–…):

  > [Корок](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44247&page=1400)
  >
  > 4. перен., розм. Те саме, що зато́р 1. Вулиці перекриті, машини сигналять, люди запізнюються на роботу, скрізь корки, вже сталося кілька аварій (Л. Костенко); На вулицях панував величезний рух, міліцейські будки опустіли, авта стояли в корку (Ю. Винничук); Корок на дорогах потроху розсмоктувався
  >      (І. Роздобудько).

Але вважається, що на цей словник мали вплив радянські сили, що зближували українську і російську мову, тому звернімося до сайту r2u.org.ua.

Там ви знайдете таку інформацію:

- Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов):

  > Затор подвод - **заві́з**
- Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)

  > Зато́ръ = 2. **тїсно́та, тиск, ти́снява.** *— Така тїснота, що й києм не протиснеш. С. Ш. — І хлопцїв чортів тиск було. С. Ш. — Така тиснява, що й не пропхаєшся.*

*(Додам трохи від себе (від P.Vovk): цілком вірогідно, що такого слова до СРСР просто не було, бо такого явища не було у нашій реальності)*

Не знаю, чи можна довіряти цьому народному словникові, але в будь-якому разі:

- Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–

  > I. Затор – (дорожный) **ти́снява, зато́ра, затор, за́пин (запи́на), запі́р (запо́ра), тромб**:
  >
  > - затор подвод – **заві́з**;
  > - на перекрёстке затор – на перехресті **затора (тиск, тиснява, тромб)**;
  > - сильные заторы на дорогах – дороги (шляхи) **заторовано**. *[В мене під вікнами третю добу **затор** (Ю.Джугастрянська). Ширлі <...>, вилаявши двох-трьох водіїв, зуміла вирватися із **запруги** (Я.Кравець, перекл. К.Панколь). Вдаримо по дорожніх **заторах** рекордними цінами на бензин!]*

Знов від себе (від P.Vovk) додам, що [гардкорні лінґвісти](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA/) стверджують, що можна вживати як "затор", так і "корок":

> Замініть **скалькований** іменник **пробка**, коли мовиться про надмірне
>   скупчення транспорту на дорогах, на стилістично кращий варіант: **затор**,
>   **корок**.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Додам ще він себе переклад деяких моїх коментарів з [того ж питання англійською, відповідь на яке переклав P. Vovk](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/850).</sub>

Може статися так, що ці слова матимуть різне значення для тих людей, які найбільше стикаються із заторами і для яких розрізнення типів заторів є професійно важливим (водії, таксисти, далекобійники). Наприклад, принаймні частина російськомовних таксистів Києва розрізняє російські слова «пробка» (укр. «корок», «пробка») і «тянучка» (укр. «тягнучка»), називаючи першим словом лише затори при яких потік майже зовсім стоїть, а другим — при яких рух відчутний, хоч і має зменшену швидкість. Може, україномовні водії теж мають подібне розрізнення, а ми про це просто не знаємо і ведемо дискусію в стилі: «що правильніше: інтернет чи всесвітнє павутиння (обидва терміни правильні, але позначають різне)».

У мене наразі немає інформації про те, як позначають різні типи заторів україномовні таксисти. Єдине, на що я натрапив випадково в інтернеті — це уривок [статті «У Музеї ЧФ немає бомби» з газети «Експрес онлайн»](http://expres.ua/news/2012/02/21/60820-muzeyi-chf-nemaye-bomby), де пізозріло поряд розташовані два різні терміни на позначення одногой того самого:

> Але **пробка** на площі Ушакова супроводжувалася **транспортним затором** і на перехресті вул. Адмірала Октябрьського, Суворова і В. Морська.

Можливо, це залишки більш диференційованої термінології (що  часто властива лише людям відповідних професій, а тут випадково потрапила в пресу) або ми спостерігаємо спроби її народження — хоча й можливо, що це просто наслідок наміру автора запобігти тавтології.

P.S.: Ще я бачив у Facebook заклики використовувати слово «**повзяк**» у ролі відповідника до російського «тянучка» (коли рух сповільнюється, але не зупиняється) — але на практиці, здається, не застосовується.